# How to insert a newline character after each occurrence of a specific XML tag in a file?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, xml

How to insert a newline character after each occurrence of a specific XML tag in a file?

My file has multiple tags `</Data>` and I want to insert a NewLine character after each `</Data>` tag

I've been trying various combinations with `sed` but it never inserts the newline character :(

The latest was `sed '/<\/Data\>/ a \n'`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's:</Data>:&\
:g'
```

Or when calling sed from bash or other shell that supports `$'\<char>'` to expand an escape sequence:

```
sed 's:</Data>:&\'$'\n'':g'
```

Or with GNU `sed`:

```
sed 's:</Data>:&\n:g'
```

e.g.:

```
$ printf 'foo</Data>bar</Data>etc\n'
foo</Data>bar</Data>etc
$
$ printf 'foo</Data>bar</Data>etc\n' | sed 's:</Data>:&\n:g'
foo</Data>
bar</Data>
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most elegant but it works:

```bsh
sed 's/\(<\/Data>\)/\1\n/ig'
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed  '/<\/Data>/ a \\n'` will insert the newline, however, if the string exists more than once in a line (typical xml may be one long line) it simply appends a newline after it instead of after every occurrence.

If you really want a newline after every occurrence, `sed  's/\(<\/Data>\)/\1\n/g'` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just formatting the `Data` tag, you can format the whole XML file with newlines after each XML nodes. This is the proper solution.

Using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) is not elegant and not universal nor a proper solution.

Think of a [`CDATA`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean) section from within your XML with:

```
<![CDATA[foobar</Data>qux]]>
```

Instead, using an XML parser like [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php):

```
xmlstarlet format -R file.xml
```

Example:

```
cat file.xml
<foo>
<a>jkj</a><data>fghj</data><x>w</x>
</foo>
```

```
$ xmlstarlet fo -R file
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
  <a>jkj</a>
  <data>fghj</data>
  <x>w</x>
</foo>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried in python

```
cat inputfile

san</Data>abhi</Data>san
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
g="</Data>"
import re
k=open('k.txt','r')
for i in k:
    m="{0}".format(g+"\n")
    q=re.sub(g,"{0}",i).format(m)
    print q
```

output

```
san</Data>
abhi</Data>
san
```